# 'If' function in google docs

Tags: function, if-statement, google-docs

I know how Excel works, but Google Docs is not the same.  I have one function in Excel which I want to put into Google Docs. Can you help?

```
=IF(A2="paypal";((A4*B4)+A4);A4)

   A         B
1
2  PAYPAL
3  60        4%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(LOWER(TRIM(A2))="paypal";((A4*B4)+A4);A4)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the google docs support site](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364), the correct syntax is:

```
IF(logical_expression, value_if_true, value_if_false)
```

So in your case, you simply need to replace the semicolons (`;`) with commas (`,`):

```
=IF(A2="paypal", (A4*B4)+A4, A4)
```

Also, be careful with case sensitivity: `"PAYPAL" != "paypal"`. You'll either need to be consistent, or convert the string to lower case.